# Mongoose date $gte operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to write query for last week but it is not working as expected in mongoDB.

```
[{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'reviews',
        localField: 'groupReviews',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'groupReviews'
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        $and: [{
                _id: {
                    $eq: ObjectId('5f247eea8ad8eb53883f4a9b')
                }
            },
            {
                "groupReviews.reviewCreated": {
                    $gte: ISODate('2020-06-20T10:24:51.303Z')
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        count: {
            $size: "$groupReviews",
        },
        groupReviews: {
            $slice: ["$groupReviews", 0, 20],
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "groupReviews.reviewCreated": -1
    }
}]
```

the actual result: above code returning results which is older than 2020-06-20.

the expected result:  it should not display older than 2020-06-20.

I am attaching an image for more reference.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0klT.png)

Comment: Why are you showing results as an image? How is the query being run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$match` stages matches entire documents, not individual array elements.  If the array contains at least one element that satisfies the `$gte` condition, the document will be matched and passed along the pipeline.

If you want to remove the individual array elements that are older than the given date, you could either

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#unwind-aggregation) the array before matching and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) to rebuild it with only the matching entries
- Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) in your `$project` stage to eliminate the unwanted elements prior to slicing